# discord.py delete author message after executing command

Tags: discord.py

I need the bot to delete the message from the command author, and leave the bot message. Any help will be appreciated! thank you.

I have already tried looking for a answer on google but nothing has worked

Comment: Which version of discord.py are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain the message that called the command by passing the context with the command using the `pass_context` option.  You can use the [`Client.delete_message`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.delete_message) coroutine to delete messages.

```
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def deletethis(ctx):
    await bot.say('Command received')
    await bot.delete_message(ctx.message)
    await bot.say('Message deleted')

bot.run('token')
```

Comment: im getting a error.. this is my current code if it helps at all: https://pastebin.com/5yvXwZQj

thank you!

Comment: @lizziehopkins The context will be passed as the first argument of your command.  So it should be `async def kick(ctx, user: discord.Member):`

Comment: @lizziehopkins And you'll want to change `bot.delete_message` to `client.delete_message`.

Answer (score 3):

I'm kinda late here. I tried implementing this with the new 1.0 terms but couldn't make it work. If anyone has an updated version, please do tell

Edit: I found that the new best way of doing it is to just add this at the end of the function:

```
await ctx.message.delete()
```

No need for a separate delete function anymore.