# How can I delete a message in discord.py after a command was executed by an user?

Tags: discord, discord.py

I am trying to program a function that deletes the message with the command sent by the user.

E.g.:

- User sends command /delmes
- Bot sends a response to the command
- Bot deletes the message sent by the user

Everything I was able to find until now (that would help me) was this Stack Overflow Thread: [discord.py delete author message after executing command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49352368/discord-py-delete-author-message-after-executing-command)

But when I used the code, as described in the solutions, I only received **AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'delete_message'**.

The discord.py API Reference (https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrating.html#models-are-stateful / https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=delete%20message#message) only revealed that some of the code had changed with newer versions.
So to speak **client.delete_message** would change to **Message.delete()**, if I interpreted it correctly!

After changing the code to what I thought it must be I received: **NameError: name 'Message' is not defined**

This is my code at the very last moment. (I am relatively new to discord.py and only used Python in school)

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import random
import json

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '/', case_insensitive=True)

@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def delcommes(ctx):
    await ctx.send("This is the response to the users command!")
    await Message.delete(ctx.message, delay=3)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't understand your question very good but as far as I understand, when command executed, then after bot sends message, you want to delete the command message, in that case it's `/delmes`. You can use `await ctx.message.delete()`.

```py
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def delcommes(ctx):
    await ctx.send("This is the response to the users command!")
    await ctx.message.delete()
```

Comment: Ok, thanks! I now see my problem! I had once tried ctx.message.delete() but still had ctx.message inside the brackets, like pointed out in the older versions of discord.py and a question I linked above!